# How to Add item to start of list using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How can I use Groovy to add an item to the beginning of a list?

Answer (score 54):

```
list.add(0, myObject);
```

You can also read this for some other valuable examples:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

Answer (score 26):

Another option would be using the spread operator `*` which expands a list into its elements:

```
def list = [2, 3]
def element = 1

assert [element, *list] == [1, 2, 3]
```

Another alternative would be to put the element into a list and concatenate the two lists:

```
assert [element] + list == [1, 2, 3]​
```

Comment: FYI, if running within a jenkins pipeline via Groovy CPS then  newList.addAll(oldList) is a better option.  The CPS will not tolerate the '*' operator

Answer (score 9):

**Caution!**

From Groovy 2.5:

```
list.push( myObject )
```

Prior to Groovy 2.5 `list.push` **appends** ... but from 2.5/2.6 (not yet Beta) it will (it seems) **prepend**, "to align with Java"... indeed, `java.util.Stack.push` has always **prepended**.

In fact this `push` method does not belong to `List`, but to [GDK 2.5 DefaultGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.0-beta-3/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#push(List%3CT%3E,%20T)), signature `<T> public static boolean push(List<T> self, T value)`.  However, because of Groovy syntax magic we shall write as above: `list.push( myObject )`.

Answer (score 5):

```
def list = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

list.plus(0, 5)

assert list == [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

You can find more examples at this [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ug/2011/04/groovy-goodness-add-items-to-list-at.html)

Comment: Interesting find.  Question is, um, why? Java's `list.add( n, object )` seems perfectly serviceable.  Not sure what I think about Groovy doubling methods for the sake of it (unless there's a reasonable explanation of course).  Also, wouldn't it have been more helpful to add `addFirst` and `addLast`, as from java's `Deque`?

Comment: @mikerodent, `list.plus` returns a _copy_ of the original list with the new element added (immutable operation, the operand stays untouched), while `list.add` just adds the element to the operand list.